# Execute a program from the cmd with arguments

Tags: c#, process, cmd, command-line-arguments

I have a program that needed running from the cmd with arguments, say the execute file called

> program.exe

And i need to run it from the cmd with args, the whole command in the cmd look like this:

```
c:\ram\program.exe /path = c:\program files\NV
```

As you can see the path is : "c:\ram\"

The execute file is : "program.exe"

The args that i need to send is : `/path = c:\program files\NV`

How can i do it ?

I try to open process like this :

```
string strArguments = @"/path = c:\program files\NV";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "program.exe";
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\ram\\";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = strArguments;
p.Start();
```

And its not good, i figure that the problem could be that i'm not accessing the exe file from the CMD, maybe i'm wrong...any body got idea how can i do it ?

Thanks

Comment: The code line p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\ram\"; doesn't work. It should be p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"c:\ram\";

Comment: i miss wrote it in my message in my program its :
 p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\ram\\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these things

`p.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\ram\\program.exe";` without setting `Working Directory`

and this one is more likely the source of the problem

```
string strArguments = @"/path = ""c:\program files\NV""";
```

When there is a space in a path, you have to enclose the whole path in quotation marks. The complete code is as follows

```
string strArguments = @"/path=""c:\program files\NV""";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\ram\program.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = strArguments;
p.Start();
```

It should do exactly what are you trying to do.

> 1.run "cmd.exe".
>
> 2.go to this dir: "c:\ram\" (in the cmd of course).
>
> 3.execute the file "program.exe" with this argument: "/path = c\:program files\NV"

It takes the program.exe in the c:\ram\ folder and executes it using cmd with the specified arguments.

Comment: The problem that i'm facing is not to get the process "program.exe" to execute, i succsed to execute the program my problem is that i need to pass args to the program and this could be done from the cmd, as you can see i'm not open the exe from the cmd as i needed, how can i open the cmd and from the cmd to execute my program.exe
?

Comment: and get to the path i need in the cmd and pass the relevant args ?

Comment: You english is not so good. I don't really understand your first comment. You are running an application from which you want to run cmd and from that cmd run this `c:\ram\program.exe /path = c:\program files\NV` command, is that right?

Comment: ill rephrase it, i'm trying to simulate in my code this actions:
1.run "cmd.exe".
2.go to this dir: "c:\ram\" (in the cmd of course).
3.execute the file "program.exe" with this argument: "/path = c\:program files\NV".

How can i simulate this procedure in my code ?
Thank you!

Comment: @RonKah I thought so. Try out the code in my answer, I included the complete code snippet. Just copy it over to your project and try it out.